# How to make a route change automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Lets say I have the route `localhost/somefolder/somecontroller/someaction` and I want that when I enter that in the browser, the app returns `localhost/somecontroller/someaction`.

I have this setup because when I published to my IIS the routes stopped working with `../../` and `~/` and also `/somecontroller/`, I have to use `/appname/somecontroller/someaction`.

So now I can't test my app properly on Visual Studio, I would have to publish it to test it instead of being able to run it because now it wont find the routes...

Alternatively, is it possible to include `@url.action` in a viewbag? many of my links are managed by my code, so they are sent inside big viewbags like

```cs
ViewBag.Button =   "<button onclick=\"window.location.replace('/somefolder/somecontroller/someaction')\">"
```

would this work?

```cs
ViewBag.Button =   "<button onclick=\"window.location.replace('@Url.Action(\"somecontroller\",\"someaction\")')\">"
```

EDIT: Mainly at this point what I mostly want is to be able to test my app on my visual studio without changing my routes, maybe temporarily have that setup, then when its time to publish undo the setup.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that your application is being published as a subsite of another website?

Comment: Just do `ViewBag.Button = $"<button onclick=\"window.location.replace('{Url.Action("somecontroller", "someaction")}');\">";` A couple notes: `~` should be relative to the application root (which should be the folder where you published). You should be using links to navigate, and buttons for actions.

Comment: @jpaugh Yes, it was published to the default website, but my app has no relation to the app that has its index there

Comment: @HereticMonkey when I used ~/ it worked on my localhost, but when moved to iis it stopped working, my folder looks like /app/scripts, /app/views/, /app/controllers, etc

Comment: @SGP I would imagine that you could add a URL rewrite somewhere in your HTTP pipeline that would rewrite all URLs of the form `/app/...` to `/...` ?

Comment: @Versailles Do you mean to add a URL rewrite to the IIS configuration? Yes, I think that would help but I would have to first undo the route changes I made in visual studio to make it run in the IIS. do you know of a way to do the url rewrite but in visual studio?

Comment: @SGP I can only find information about doing it in ASP.NET Core using [Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-2.2) (read the part about rewrites, not redirects) but I'm sure there are ways if you're not using .NET Core. It seems like the appropriate solution for you because adding a rewriting rule in code will both allow you to test in Visual Studio, and the rule can stay in your app even after publish